# Program not responding to linux signals sent from terminal without continuous printing on terminal

Tags: c, linux, signal-handling

I have a C program that goes like:

```
while(1){
    if(flag1){
         ...
    }
    if(flag2){
         ...
    }
}
```

Now these flags will be raised in handlers for SIGINT AND SIGTSTP signals. The terminal just shows     ^C and ^Z when Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Z is entered, but the conditional code blocks are not executed.
However the exact same program, but if I give a printf like below:

```
while(1){
    printf("  ");
    if(flag1){
         ...
    }
    if(flag2){
         ...
    }
}
```

The program responds to the Ctrl+Z or Ctrl+C signals, and the respective conditional code blocks are executed. 
Could someone explain this behavior? I am not sure why keeping the terminal busy with something being printed continuously, makes my program respond to the signals, while not otherwise.

Comment: Why not post the complete code so we can help?

Comment: the program not responding to Linux signals, how shall I know that just looking at the skeleton while loop. post the problematic code and error code, that will help to understand the problem you face.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/schegde/fafc10fa6947c2bd738d3334198ba1f1#file-transfer-c

Comment: The rio_writen and rio_readnb are functions that write and read from network socket.

Comment: Try to define flags as volatile.

Comment: @ErkiA Yes! that was indeed the case! Thanks. Could you re-add your  explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional code blocks could be optimized out, because compiler doesn't know these variables can change out of the loop. Define flags as volatile, i.e.

```
volatile int flag1;
...
```

This way compiler knows not to make any assumptions about the values of these variables.